# type_traits file not found (Xcode 5)

Tags: xcode, macos, c++11, clang++

i'm trying to build an application that uses wxWidgets library. but i get a preprocessor error that says 'type_traits file not found'. i've followed the answers in the questions [XCode 4.5 'tr1/type_traits' file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219007/xcode-4-5-tr1-type-traits-file-not-found) and [Xcode 4.3 and C++11 include paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345271/xcode-4-3-and-c11-include-paths) but i'm still unable to resolve that error. how to configure xcode to include the type_traits file?
EDIT : i figured it out. libc++ needs deployment target >= OS X 10.7

Comment: You set the dialect to `c++11` and the library to `libc++` and you still get the error?

Comment: ya.. here is my configuration :<br> //:configuration = Debug
CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD = c++0x
CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY = libstdc++

//:configuration = Release
CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD = c++0x
CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY = libstdc++

Comment: `libstdc++` is not `libc++`, however I am not claiming that this is the cause of the problem.

Comment: oh i'm sorry. i copy pasted an old configuration and here is my actual configuration : Debug
CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD = c++0x
CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY = libc++

//:configuration = Release
CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD = c++0x
CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY = libc++

Comment: Can you post the full command and its output? You can find this command in Xcode, by pressing command+8 and checking the output. This will avoid having everybody try a bunch of questions and allow people to better help you.