# Boost C++ compiler error on type_traits in Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, c++11, boost

This question has been asked with many variants but none seemed to solve this problem. I recently transitioned from Windows to Mac and am giving up the Windows ppl.h parallel tools and replacing them with boost/thread.hpp to be more portable in the future. However, I cannot get boost thread to compile. I am running boost_1_56_0 and Xcode 5.1.1

I downloaded boost and added the boost path to my Header Search Paths and it resulted in errors like this when compiling. I am using C++ Standard Library set to libc++ and C++ Language Dialect set to GNU++11.

```
/Users/xxxx/Documents/boost_1_56_0/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_duration.hpp:24:21: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'hour_type' (aka 'int')

/Users/xxxx/Documents/boost_1_56_0/boost/date_time/gregorian_calendar.ipp:82:12: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'date_int_type' (aka 'unsigned int')
```

I saw suggestions to fix the problem by changing the C++ Standard Library to libstdc++ and C++ Language Dialect set to C++11.

Now I get a single error:

```
/Users/xxxx/Documents/boost_1_56_0/boost/thread/detail/move.hpp:31:10: 'type_traits' file not found.
```

The same question was asked here: [type_traits file not found (Xcode 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22855113/type-traits-file-not-found-xcode-5)

The asker figured out a fix but I am running OSX 10.9.4 and my deployment target is 10.9 but the issue still occurs.

I could use some help to get past the compiler errors to start porting my existing programs off ppl and onto boost. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your original warnings appear to be a [known bug in boost](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7687). I believe the version of libstdc++ that comes with OS X is ancient and doesn't support C++11 features. Just use libc++.

Comment: It is - as is any version of GCC that might remain from previous. insoles of Xcode.  It has, at best, a broken and incomplete C++11 implementation. 

Both are deprecated and replaced by libc++ and clang respectively - both of which are thoroughly compliant.

Comment: Ok I see now that the original errors about 'Implicit conversion loses integer precision' is actually just a warning. However, I also get these errors, which are not warnings:  "boost::system::system_category()", referenced from: and   "boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
I installed boost using homebrew and running 'brew doctor'. Before doing the 'brew install', is there a specific command to make homebrew create libraries to work with multithreading?

Comment: After running 'brew build boost', all of the libraries get created in /usr/local/Cellar. In order to get multithreading working, I had to add libboost_system-mt.dylib and libboost_thread-my.dylib to Build Settings -> Link Binary With Libraries. This fixed the compiler and linker errors and I was able to do some tests to verify multithreading is working.